# How to add remote Maven repository in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I need to add some external dependencies to my Maven project. For example I need this library: https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client-core/5.1.0/ I'm struggling with adding the repository in which this library is located.

I've already tried:
- adding https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Remote Jar Repositories -> Maven Jar Repositories
- adding repository to settings.xml following this tutorial http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories, settings file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0                 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testname</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>atlassianReleases</id>
                <name>Atlassian Releases</name>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>                  
                <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>testname</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

- updating added repository via Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> Repositories
- RMB on pom.xml -> Maven -> Reimport
- rebuilding the project

Of course I have correct dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I still get error messages that used packages do not exist.

Edit:
I noticed that in my local repository I have com\atlassian\jira\jira-rest-java-client-core\5.1.0 folder but only with .pom file, _remote.repositories and .pom.sha1 file.

Edit2:
The problem was caused by my VPN settings, solved.

Comment: Are you setting the settings.xml file path under the Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven -> "User settings file" field and overriding it?

Comment: The path to settings.xml is correct, I still get the same result no matter if override checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

first you must delete com\atlassian\jira\jira-rest-java-client-core folder in .m2 directory 
and again run mvn commands.
***in intellij if you changed pom.xml file ,maven plugin automatic run again**

Comment: I still get only .pom file, _remote.repositories and .pom.sha1 file.

Comment: can i see your pom.xml file?

Comment: Unfortunately no because of company NDA. It just contains more dependencies, nothing unusual.

Comment: set '/'  at the end of url that set in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Remote Jar Repositories -> Maven Jar Repositories

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you pom.xml `repositories` section:

```
<repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
</repository>
```

See documentation here https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/atlassian-maven-repositories-2818705/